# Как можно задать создаваемому элементу ID

Tags: javascript

Как можно задать создаваемому элементу ID, или имя?

```
<script>
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.width = '100px';
  div.style.height = '100px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.top = '300px';
  div.style.left = '300px';
  div.style.background = 'red';
  div.className = 'div'+n;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  n++;     

  document.getElementsByClassName('div'+(n-1))[0].setAttribute(name,'div');
</script>
```

Comment: `div.id = 'id' + n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так же как и класс

```
div.id = "id сам придумаешь";
```